# Does Windows 8 Phone support JQuery ajax call when using PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm using the PhoneGap platform.  Does Windows Phone 8 support a JQuery Mobile ajax call?  My code:

```
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'some URL',
      data: senddata,
      dataType: 'text'  
  });
```

This call works on iPhone and Android device but not on Windows 8 Phone.  Is anyone using ajax to post to a URL on Windows 8 Phone via using JQuery and PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the options below:

```
$(document).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
  $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
});
```